# Tuple unpacking in function arguement

Tags: python, python-3.x, tuples

In the following function, `args[i]` should unpack into the arguments of the function func via the `*` before it, however what gets passed in is a list. What am I missing?

```
def mymap(func, *seq):
    args = list(zip(seq))
    ret = []
    for i in range(len(args)):
        print(type(args[i]))
        ret.append( func(*args[i]) )
    return ret

f = lambda x: x+2

mymap(f, [1,2,3])
```

Comment: What would the expected output be? `*seq` captures a number of extra arguments, your `[1, 2, 3]` is just **one** argument.

Comment: Your `list(zip(seq))` line is especially puzzling; you have just the one tuple (`seq`), containing one list (`[1, 2, 3]`). What did you expect `args` to contain?

Answer (score 5):

The `*` packs in a function definition and unpacks in a function call.

Defining a new function:

```
def func1(*args):
    print(args)
```

this packs:

```
>>> func1(1, 2)
(1, 2)
```

A function with two parameters

```
def func2(a, b):
    print(a)
    print(b)
```

can be called with a sequence using the `*`:

```
>>> func2(*[1, 2])
1
2
```